# Possible ways to do async over sync

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asynchronous, async-await

I have an ASP.NET API which exposes some DB operations. DB API itself is synchronous and can't be changed. I'm aware that using Task.Run in ASP.NET is a bad idea and I was going to make the web API sync but started to think about different possible ways about making DB operations async and wonder if any of these is a good idea.

1. Use `Task.FromResult`

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<Result> Get()
{
      return Task.FromResult(DBOperation());
}
```

This feels like it'd only be good just to allocate `Task` in addition to result.

2. Use `ValueTask`

```
return new ValueTask<Result>(DBOperation());
```

Feels same as Task (just allocate more)? Not sure if ValueTask being struct would be better or worse.

3. Use `TaskCompletionSource`

```
public Task<Result> DBOperation()
{
    TaskCompletionSource<Result> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<Result>();
    //db call
    tcs.SetResult(<result>);
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

Not sure if it'd help.

4. Use `Task.Yield`

```
public Task<Result> DBOperation()
{
    await Task.Yield();
    //db call
}
```

Maybe?

What do you think?

Comment: Based on `[HttpGet]` attribute on `Get()` I see no point in introducing here async over sync, just change the return type of action to `Result`.

Comment: Those are all wrong and they're effectively synchronous. `Task.Run` is actually a better option, I wouldn't suggest it either as you're likely to run into concurrency issues accessing the database from across multiple threads.

Comment: As [Stephen Toub said](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/should-i-expose-asynchronous-wrappers-for-synchronous-methods/) back in 2012: don't.

Comment: Just return the value. Web requests are already handled by separate threads, so all of the options would just waste CPU cycles. You'd only gain something from `async/await` if the IO, in this case the actual database calls, can be executed asynchronously. If your driver doesn't support real async, find another one or use synchronous operations. For example, MySQL's Connector/NET fakes async calls, so *everyone* uses the truly open source [MySQLConnector.Net](https://mysqlconnector.net/) instead.

Comment: @dstr `DB API itself is synchronous and can't be changed.`  are you sure? What database are you calling and how? There may be alternative drivers that can work asynchronously

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> wonder if any of these is a good idea.

Nope.

Every attempt at async-over-sync on ASP.NET causes additional memory overhead. And some of them (`Task.Run` and `Task.Yield`) also cause an additional thread switch.

The whole point of asynchronous code is to free up a thread, but if you have an unavoidable blocking call, then the thread *can't* be freed, by definition. As Panagiotis pointed out, you might be able to replace the blocking call with an asynchronous one, but if not, then async-over-sync won't help you.