# How do I call synchronous methods in parallel?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I need help in understanding how async/await works in this scenario.
I have 4 methods

```
async Task<int> get1()
{
    await Task.Yield();
    Console.WriteLine("get1");
    return 1;
}

async Task<int> get2()
{
    await Task.Yield();
    Console.WriteLine("get2");
    return 2;
}

async Task<int> get3()
{
    await Task.Yield();
    Console.WriteLine("get3");
    return 3;
}

async Task<int> get4()
{
    await Task.Yield();
    Console.WriteLine("get4");
    return 4;
}
```

I call them from the following method

```
async Task<int> doMultiMethods()
{
    // we have the list of tasks - taskList
    // we have the task that lets us know when all the tasks in that list are completed - resultTask
    // we have the results of the task that waited for all the tasks - resultTask (after resultTask is awaited)
    // we have the results of all the tasks - results
    Task<int> x = get1();
    Task<int> y = get2();
    Task<int> z = get3();
    Task<int> a = get4();
    List<Task<int>> taskList = new List<Task<int>> { x, y, z, a };

    var resultTask = Task.WhenAll(taskList);
    int[]? results = await resultTask;
    //await results;

    if (resultTask.IsCompleted && results.Any())
    {
        foreach (var r in results)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(r);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Done");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

and my output looks like below with the first 4 lines being "random" each time I call it.

```
get4
get3
get1
get2
1
2
3
4
Done
```

What I don't understand is why I need await Task.Yield() to get the methods to run asynchronously. If I remove all the await Task.Yield() from all the methods, my code outputs the get methods (first 4 lines of output) in order every time leading me to believe they are running synchronously.

What is the correct way to call methods so that they run asynchronously?  My main issue is the warning

> This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread.

AND making sure they are actually running asynchronously.

Comment: I got the await Task.Yield() code from this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.yield?view=net-7.0

Comment: `leading me to believe they are running synchronously` - they run in order. Asynchronously. Asynchronously does not mean simultaneously.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? If you have a synchronous method, what does "run it asynchronously" mean to you?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to accomplish.  No actual asynchronous operations are used here.  Are you trying to use Tasks to create multiple threads for synchronous operations to run in parallel?

Comment: Probably duplicate of @StephenCleary answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70769792/possible-ways-to-do-async-over-sync but since Stephen is here not closing :)

Comment: I want methods get1, get2, get3 and get4 to all run at the same time.

Comment: @spacebread "to all run at the same time" is parallel/concurrent and *not* asynchronous. Please [edit] the qestion to clarify that (and hopefully clarify that you have good understanding of the difference)

Comment: What you said David and Alexei is what I am trying to do. I think you helped flip a light on for me as I kept associating parallel with asynchronous.

Comment: async means the code inside the method will run asynchronously, correct? I kept thinking that async meant the method would/could be called asynchronously.

Comment: @spacebread No, `async` means "this method may use the `await` keyword in its body". All methods are called in the same way, which is synchronously. Your async method is called synchronously and synchronously returns "something that will be completed later" (a `Task`).

Comment: As a side note, names of methods in C# are [Pascal-cased](https://github.com/ktaranov/naming-convention/blob/master/C%23%20Coding%20Standards%20and%20Naming%20Conventions.md). `Get1`, `Get2`, `Get3`, `Get4` and `DoMultiMethods` is correct.

Comment: I am downvoting the question solely for advertising the `await Task.Yield();` as a means for offloading work to the `ThreadPool`. This is not the intended usage of this API. My arguments are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74558319/async-function-not-launching-asynchronously/74558485#comment131611819_74558485) (as comments).

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Your link has a wealth of information. I fear I was just not able to do a good Google search to find the information I needed to solve my confusion.  And this is not an endorsement for using await Task.Yield(), quite the opposite, I didn't feel like it was the right answer so that is why I asked.

Comment: Spacebread yep, I understand that you are just trying to solve a problem and it's not your intention to advertise anything, so from this perspective my downvote is unfair. Sorry for this, but I am too committed at downvoting any post that demonstrates the `Task.Yield` utilized for the purpose of offloading. There are a few things in .NET that make me mad, and the `Task.Yield` happens to be one of them.

Answer (score 2):

I should use Task.Run to call my get methods and don't define them as async. As shown on this page - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/asynchronous-programming/async-scenarios

```
async Task<int> DoMultiMethodsAsync2()
{
    Task<int> x = Task.Run(() => Get1());
    Task<int> y = Task.Run(() => Get2());
    Task<int> z = Task.Run(() => Get3());
    Task<int> a = Task.Run(() => Get4());
    List<Task<int>> taskList = new List<Task<int>> { x, y, z, a };

    var resultTask = Task.WhenAll(taskList);
    int[]? results = await resultTask;
    //await results;

    if (resultTask.IsCompleted && results.Any())
    {
        foreach (var r in results)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(r);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Done");
    }

    return 0;
}


int Get1()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Get1");
    return 1;
}

int Get2()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Get2");
    return 2;
}

int Get3()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Get3");
    return 3;
}

int Get4()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Get4");
    return 4;
}
```

Sample Output

```
Get3
Get2
Get4
Get1
1
2
3
4
Done
```